# Scala Optional best practices

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, syntax, utility

```
def canAppendOffset(offset: Long): Boolean = {
  toRelative(offset).isDefined
}

private def toRelative(offset: Long): Option[Int] = {
  val relativeOffset = offset - baseOffset
  if (relativeOffset < 0 || relativeOffset > Int.MaxValue) None
  else Some(relativeOffset.toInt)
}
```

I get confused when running into the aforementioned code. The code if from Kafka LogSegment. I am wondering why we need a Optional here rather than simply return a  boolean in `canAppendOffset()`. It looks unnecessary to me why we need to create an Optional and access an field which records the boolean value I need.
I think there must be some logic in software design aspects. Could anyone give any suggestions on where and why to use Optional in Scala?

Comment: As a note, **Option** is not only made for dealing with `null`. The Option represents the _effect_ of a missing value, or a computation that can't return a value. Most languages deal with this using `null`; e.g. Java. And that is why the constructor of Option catches `null`. However it is perfectly fine _(and encouraged)_ to return optional values even when there is no null, just to signal, this value here may or many not exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There appears to be a couple of misconceptions here.

> ...create an Optional and access a field which records the boolean value...

There is no field here. `isDefined` is a method in the `Option` class that tests whether this instance is `Some()` or `None`.

> ...why we need an Optional here rather than simply return a boolean in `canAppendOffset()`.

But `canAppendOffset()` *does* "simply return a `Boolean`". It's `toRelative()` that "creates" the `Option` and it does that because, while it is *supposed* to return a "relative" from the given offset, it might actually fail to do so if a valid result is impossible.

So it returns an `Option[Int]`, thus telling the caller, "Here's `Some(relative)` if it can be calculated from the given offset, but it's `None` if I can't calculate a good result for you."

Comment: That description of `isDefined` is a bit misleading. `isDefined` can be used to test an instance of `Option` but the method itself does not test anything, it just returns a constant.

Comment: Hi @Tim. Before posting I visited the [source](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/706ef1b291134a5e5bce2275df2c222261f73451/src/library/scala/Option.scala#L169) and since `def isDefined` is `!isEmpty`, and `def isEmpty` is `this eq None`, I thought the description was pretty accurate. Where is said constant?

Comment: @jwvh Thanks for the clarification, yeah I see, isDefined is a method. I understand what you said about the reason to use Optional. But here it seems if the conditions is not met, a false can simply been returned, since there is no a false return in the `isRelative()`. I think Optional would be useful if there is chance of invoked something like a NullPointerException but here it seems no this kind of risk exists.

Comment: I know `canAppend` just returns a boolean ,what I am wondering is just why it doesn't simply do the condition check inside it self, an extra `isRelative()` seems a bit redundant to me.

Comment: @BoyuZhang; You mean why not do the `relativeOffset` calculations and testing inside `canAppendOffset()` and be done with it, as @YuvalItzchadov suggests in his answer? It would, indeed, be more efficient to cut `toRelative()` out of the picture, but then you have duplicate code for determining if the given offset is valid. What if the definition of a valid offset changes? Then you'd have to hunt down both places in the code base where the calculation is done. These are the trade-offs software designers have to make.

Comment: My apologies, you are quite correct, I was looking at `isEmpty` not `isDefined`. Interestingly in 2.12 `isEmpty` is overloaded to `def isEmpty = true` for `None` and `def isEmpty = false` for `Some` so different to 2.13

Comment: @jwvh Yeah I see, a lot of time it is just a trade-off, most of time there is no perfect choice. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

> It looks unnecessary to me why we need to create an Optional and
>   access an field which records the boolean value I need.

I agree. It *would* make sense to create a `toRelative` method returning an `Option[Int]` if it was used in other places where the calculated offset would actually be used. It could very well be that this method was previously used for other use cases, and understanding what the relative offset was actually used.

If you wanted only to know if the offset can be appended, you can simplify:

```
private def canAppendOffset(offset: Long): Boolean = {
  val relativeOffset = offset - baseOffset
  relativeOffset >= 0 && relativeOffset < Int.MaxValue
}
```